# How to reconnect to network file

Tags: ssms

How do I reconnect the open files in SSMS to their network locations for change tracking?

After disconnecting my laptop from my network at work and then reconnecting through a VPN the sql script files that I have open in SSMS no longer recognize change tracking. If I want I can close and re-open the files, or save them again, and they re-establish their connection with the network path, and will then notify me if it's updated outside of my instance of SSMS, but is there a better way to just reconnect the file to the network so that it will resume it's change tracking?